# Unsupported operation: _Namespace while using Directory.current dart

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I want to save a network image in my local storage, so I need to get the path, but I got this error Unsupported operation: _Namespace

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:adminsignin/style/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(link));
    response;
            // final file = File('ImageTest/my_image.jpg');
            // await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
            Directory pathh = Directory.current;
    print('pathh: ${pathh.absolute}');
} catch (e) {
    // Handle the error when http.get fails
    print('Errorr: $e');
}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest that you [not `catch` everything](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-catches-without-on-clauses) and just let the exception go uncaught so that you can easily get the full error message and stacktrace.

Comment: Additionally, creating a minimal example that can reproduce the problem would help a lot.

Comment: this is the full error message without catch: Error: Unsupported operation: _Namespace

Comment: Only those two lines :   final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(link));
          Directory pathh= Directory.current;  give the error message

Comment: Edit your question to include the stacktrace.  And that is not a reproducible example.  A reproducible example allows *other people* to copy-and-paste your code to encounter the same problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.